# ORA-01722: invalid number- select, alias

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't write complicated select and alias statements because of  these errors.

What's wrong with this select statement from Hr tables

```
SELECT  FIRST_NAME+', '+LAST_NAME+' , '+email  AS NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: Oracle uses || for concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it like this :

```
SELECT  FIRST_NAME || ', ' || LAST_NAME  AS 'NAME'

FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Yes, as Mihai mentioned - the `||` is concatenation

Comment: yea it worked, i edited the question, can you help me again! because i have the error with many columns